# scala define function like ruby-way

Tags: ruby, scala

In ruby, you can call the following code for printing `"foo"` in the console:

```
p "foo"
```

or

```
puts "foo"
```

And it  prints `"foo"`. In scala, I created this function:

```
def p(forPrint: Any): Unit = {
  println(forPrint)
}
```

but it needs to be called like `p("foo")`. How can I write:

```
puts "foo"
```

and print in scala with such syntax?

Or, like if `Array.map{} equal Array map{}`

can i

```
"foo" p equal println("foo")
```

Comment: It's really not clear what your expectations are here. `puts` will display text. Do you need a different behaviour?

Comment: I wanna call { p "foo" } instead of { println("foo") } is it even possible?

Comment: If you need a terse language, try Haskell then. `p "foo"` can be valid Haskell for printing "foo".

Comment: You can use an implicit value class to get "foo" p, however you will end up with a feature warning as it can lead to odd bugs with line break wrapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this method:

```
def p(forPrint: Any): Unit = println(forPrint)
```

It is not possible in Scala to call it like this:

```
p "foo"
```

You can only omit the parentheses when calling a method from an object. For example:

```
scala> println "foo" // doesn't work
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but string literal found.
       println "foo"
               ^

scala> Console println "foo" // does work
foo
```

In the context of your example, you can place `p` in an object:

```
object Test {
   def p(forPrint: Any): Unit = println(forPrint)
}

Test p "foo"
```

The reason you can call `array toList`, instead of `array.toList`, is that `array` is an object, with a method `toList`. `p` is a method with an argument `"foo"`, which is not allowed without referencing an object explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's enforcement of brackets is *extremely* lax compared to other programming languages, so it has a syntax that's unusually sparse. This is why it's often a language of choice for writing configuration files, there's not much grit in the expression.

Technically `p(x)` is equivalent to `p x` in Ruby, but the same is not true in other languages.

As far as I can tell, [you can't do this in Scala](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) because the meaning is different.

Generally trying to force one language to behave like another creates a lot of unnecessary confusion. I'd do it the Scala way whenever possible.

Comment: but i can do { array toList } or { array.toList }  so, can i write func for {"foo" p}  ?